# Old School CTRL+F Behavior

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-edge, internet-explorer-11

I have a user who likes the pop out search box instead of the embedded search field in IE11 and Edge. Is there a way to make find pop out into its own window and run like it used to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE 11, as a user setting, under:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\
...create a new key called "Find".

Under the new Find key, create a new DWORD value called EnableFrameDlg and set it to 1.

Regards,

Comment: Glad it helped.  The power of Process Monitor at work. :)